# Can I use lag screws, lag bolts to hang swing vertically from a wood beam?

Tags: wood, screws, bolts

I need to hang a swing (picture attached) from a large wood beam in my living room.  The beam is 1 foot high and 1/2 foot wide. (quite strong).

I am planning to use 2 metal faceplates . Each faceplate has a hook welded to it and has 3 holes.  The holes are 1/2 inch in diameter.

The swing seating area is a flat plank.

Need to support up to 1000 lbs total.

Q: Can I drill a lag screw / nut vertically to hang the swing ?  (picture)
Q: If so, what are the recommended lag screw dimensions: 
   1/2 inch diameter x 6 inches long or 
   1/2 inch diameter x 4 inches long ?

Q: alternatively, can I use a 1.2 inch diameter - sleeve anchor ?
   or is this only for concrete?

Photos attached:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
thank you

Comment: Any shock loading (people or kids jumping on it)?  How far will it swing, 5°?  15°?  45°?  This affects the bending force on the hangers shown.  What happens if it fails?  What happens if whatever is on the swing (people, or something heavy with sharp edges?) falls off, could it go through the floor?

Answer (score 1):

No, I would not trust those welds to hold for long under the loading effects due to swinging.

I would get bolts / hooks (3/8" dia min) that bolt through the plate which I would also have as 3/8" thick.

Edit, how about these:

[image]

Link to source https://www.easternjunglegym.com/heavy-duty-ductile-swing-hanger

Comment: You have got to be kidding welding is the best method for this if properly done-

Comment: @EdBeal seen too many welds fail due to cyclic loading... Obviously depends on the experience of the welder and the design - if the weld is on the reverse side as well that is a different proposition - but that is not shown on the OP's drawing as that part is only in dotted. If it was welded on both sides ie a through hole then it would be shown as a solid circle...

Comment: Look at the pictures these are professional looking parts.

Comment: Pictures should be in the post - I don't follow links as a rule...

Comment: New users often have a hard time posting pics.

Comment: Thank you Ed Beal, Solar Mike - 

I re-posted my question with inline photos (no links). 
The holes in each face plate are 1/4 inch in diameter each (total of 3 holes per plate).  There are 2 plates.  

I should be using lag bolts / screws and not anchor sleeves (which are meant for concrete).  Correct?

Thank you.

Comment: "Professional looking" (what are the criteria for this?) is not the same as "will withstand cyclic loading without fatigue failure".

Comment: @Technophile did you address me or Ed?

Comment: @SolarMike  Ed was the one who wrote "professional looking parts".

Answer (score 0):

I would want 4 screws as you are showing a square plate but 3ea  1/2” on either side at 4” will provide plenty of static load. since you did not state the type of beam I looked up hem fir the softest, the chart said in dry wood 230 lbs ea for shear and withdrawal 437 lbs , since you will be swinging I would cut those numbers in half and you still have enough with 3 on each side.
 Edit: after looking at your pictures the screw placement is fine for 3ea and your project should be fine those look like nice brackets.